# "Simple marketing software" or "Simplified marketing software" - which is correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I have built http://www.inboundio.com/ which is  a simplified marketing software. Now I am not sure in < title > tag of home page if I should use

> Simple inbound marketing software

OR

> Simplified inbound marketing software

?

which is more correct ? I am using simplified till now but curious to know what the English SE community think

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two mean two different things. *Simplified* means that the software package or whatever you have was made simple or simpler and was not simple by nature. *Simple* on the other hand carries a different meaning. It means that the package is simple by nature. On top of that, *software* is not countable, so you cannot say *a software*, just a side note.

Comment: Thanks, Simplified looks to be more suitable since I am certainly saying it in comparison to others. Accepting the answer, unfortunately I can't upvote you or anyone as I don't have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified Marketing Software is a better word as it suggests that the software is simple and easy to use..

Comment: Surely "Simple Marketing Software" suggests the software is simple; "simplified" merely means "made more simple" -- it could still be horrendously complex!

Answer (score 0):

"Simplified" is a comparative adjective. It means that the referenced subject is more simple or less complex than something else (which could be an earlier version of itself).

"Simple" is a non-comparative adjective. It means the referenced subject is not complex.

Both are correct. Which one you should use depends on what you want to say.

These really could be understood by refering to general refernces.